# Video Games all run 60fps and above but randomly drop 20fps

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, cpu, gaming, fps

So when I play video games on my PC, they all run at 60fps or higher but randomly throughout all my games it will drop to 25fps and lower. I know it can't be the game because it happens in all my games. I thought it may be my CPU overheating and I need a new fan because I do just have a stock fan which may not be cutting it for gaming or maybe it could be my hardrive wich is 7200rpm and only 3gb/s. I want to know what could be causing these fps drops.

My CPU is an Amd six-core 3.8Ghz
My GPU/Graphics card is an nVidia GTX 650 TI
I have 8gb of RAM
I have a 500gb hard drive with 7200rpm and 6gb/s like I said above

If you need any more information, comment.

Comment: The stock fan isn't "crappy" it does exactly what it was designed to do, after market cooling fans are only important, if you perform after market overclocking to your CPU which does not sound like you are.  All display drivers are current?

Comment: All my display drivers are current and no I'm not overclocking.

Comment: Have you had this framerate issue since you got the graphics card?  Or is it a new occurrence?

Comment: I don't actually remember when it started but I know it wasn't like that when I first put my computer together.

Comment: So yeah it wasn't like that for a while.